# java send mail on Linux: Error certification

Tags: java

I try to send mail by Java on Linux server.
I setup to run on Tomcat 6, config SSL
but I got an error message:

```
 Can't send command to SMTP host 
 javax.mail.MessagingException: Can't send command to SMTP host;
  nested exception is: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

My java code like below:

```
    String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    int port = 587;
    String username = "java.test@gmail.com";
    String password = "aabbcc";

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props);

    try {


        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("java.test@gmail.com"));
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
            InternetAddress.parse("test504@gmail.com"));
        message.setSubject("Testing Subject");
        message.setText("Dear Mail Crawler," +
                "\n\n No spam to my email, please!");


        Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
        transport.connect(host, port, username, password);


        Transport.send(message);

        System.out.println("Done");

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        System.out.println("ERROR: "+e.getMessage());
        System.out.println("ERROR: "+e.toString());

        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

If I config Tomcat without SSL -> It can send mail Success
But within SSL -> I have above error

Please help fix error. Thank guys!

Comment: If I config Tomcat without SSL -> It can send mail Success
But within SSL -> I have above error. I think there is problem with certificate file. But I dont know how to solve it

Comment: You must check whether gmail's CA is available in your JDKs keystore, for that you must either know its location or you must create your own and make it available to your application using system properties.

Answer (score 0):

I think it needs a secure TLS connection , take a look at [this link](http://blogs.oracle.com/apanicker/entry/java_code_for_smtp_server) to know how to do it